# JSF- <p:dataTable> issue with the Ajaxmethod

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am having a   `<p:dataTable>` and In a row I am having an date field where I need to show dialogue to user whenever the user changes the date by systematically or by manually an Ajax method will called to update the message from backing bean.

Here is the      code for that specific row that I am using.

```
<p:calendar value="#{dets.exceptionDueDate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                            size="10" navigator="true"
                            rendered="#{systemDetailsBean.editCmdActionflg==true and (dets.firstColumn!='1' or dets.secondColumn!='1')}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                            <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
                                listener="#{systemDetailsBean.showPopup}"
                                process="@this :SystemDetailsinfoForm:line :commentsform:commentsdt"
                                partialSubmit="true" />
                            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{systemDetailsBean.showPopup}"
                                process="@this :SystemDetailsinfoForm:line :commentsform:commentsdt"
                                partialSubmit="true" />
                            <f:attribute name="index" value="_#{index}" />
                            <f:attribute name="componentId" value="exe" />
                        </p:calendar>
```

As you can see the calendar is calling two event methods namely "dateselect" and "change"
I have added two methods coz' the user may able to provide the date in both ways maually and systematically.

The Ajax method in the backing bean is given below

```
   public void showPopup(ActionEvent event) { 

String compId = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes()
                        .get("componentId");
                int index = Integer.parseInt(((String) event.getComponent()
                        .getAttributes().get("index")).replace("_", ""));
//Blah blah...
    }
```

My problem is consider the `<p:dataTable>` is having `12 rows` the when I change the date column in a specific row, the AjaxMethod is called for `12 times`.So due to this I could not able to process some message in the Ajax method in the backing bean.

How can I able to restrict the calling of Ajax method for only one time,when I select a date column in a specific row.As you can see I can able to get the index of the row.
But I dont know how to restrict the method calling in XHTML.

Any suggestions will be really helpful to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by replacing the "process" attribute with "update" attribute and I added "execute=@this" attribute.

Here is my updated code

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect"    execute="@this"
                                listener="#{systemDetailsBean.showPopup}"
                                update="@this :SystemDetailsinfoForm:line :commentsform:commentsdt"  
                                partialSubmit="true" />
                            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{systemDetailsBean.showPopup}" execute="@this"
                                update="@this :SystemDetailsinfoForm:line :commentsform:commentsdt"
                                partialSubmit="true" />
```